# How to use Keras Multiply() with tf.Variable?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, map-function

How do I multiply `tf.keras.layers` with `tf.Variable`?

Context: I am creating a sample dependent convolutional filter, which consists of a generic filter `W` that is transformed through sample dependent shifting + scaling. Therefore, the convolutional original filter `W` is transformed into `aW + b` where `a` is sample dependent scaling and `b` is sample dependent shifting. One application of this is training an autoencoder where the sample dependency is the label, so each label shifts/scales the convolutional filter. Because of sample/label dependent convolutions, I am using `tf.nn.conv2d` which takes the actual filters as input (as opposed to just the number/size of filters) and a lambda layer with `tf.map_fn` to apply a different "transformed filter" (based on the label) for each sample. Although the details are different, this kind of sample-dependent convolution approach is discussed in this post: [Tensorflow: Convolutions with different filter for each sample in the mini-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068999/tensorflow-convolutions-with-different-filter-for-each-sample-in-the-mini-batch).

Here is what I am thinking:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  
label = keras.Input(shape=(10,)) # number of classes

num_filters = 32
shift = layers.Dense(num_filters, activation=None, name='shift')(label) # (32,)
scale = layers.Dense(num_filters, activation=None, name='scale')(label) # (32,)

# filter is of shape (filter_h, filter_w, input channels, output filters)
filter = tf.Variable(tf.ones((3,3,input_img.shape[-1],num_filters)))
# TODO: need to shift and scale -> shift*(filter) + scale along each output filter dimension (32 filter dimensions)
```

I am not sure how to implement the `TODO` part. I was thinking of `tf.keras.layers.Multiply()` for scaling and `tf.keras.layers.Add()` for shifting, but they do not seem to work with tf.Variable to my knowledge. How do I get around this? Assuming the dimensions/shape broadcasting work out, I would like to do something like this (note: the output should still be the same shape as var and is just scaled along each of the 32 output filter dimensions)

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([var, scale])
```

Comment: Can you explain your `var`'s shape?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I changed `var` to `filter` to indicate this is the convolutional filter (before shifting/scaling). It's of shape (filter_height, filter_width, input channels, output filters) which is (3,3,1,32) in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires some work and needs a custom layer. For example you [cannot use tf.Variable with tf.keras.Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718635/how-to-use-tf-lambda-and-tf-variable-at-tensorflow-2-0)

```
class ConvNorm(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, height, width, n_filters):
        super(ConvNorm, self).__init__()
        self.height = height  
        self.width = width
        self.n_filters = n_filters

    def build(self, input_shape):              
        self.filter = self.add_weight(shape=(self.height, self.width, input_shape[-1], self.n_filters),
                                 initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                 trainable=True)        
        # TODO: Add bias too


    def call(self, x, scale, shift):
        shift_reshaped = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(shift,1),1)
        scale_reshaped = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(scale,1),1)

        norm_conv_out = tf.nn.conv2d(x, self.filter*scale + shift, strides=(1,1,1,1), padding='SAME')
                
        return norm_conv_out
```

Using the layer

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

input_img = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  
label = layers.Input(shape=(10,)) # number of classes

num_filters = 32
shift = layers.Dense(num_filters, activation=None, name='shift')(label) # (32,)
scale = layers.Dense(num_filters, activation=None, name='scale')(label) # (32,)

conv_norm_out = ConvNorm(3,3,32)(input_img, scale, shift)
print(norm_conv_out.shape)
```

**Note**: Note that I haven't added bias. You will need bias as well for the convolution layer. But that's straightfoward.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. I definitely would not have been able to implement a custom layer on my own so I appreciate the help. I have a few follow-up questions which may be obvious. 1) Are `scale_reshaped` and `shift_reshaped` accidentally included twice inside `call()`? 2) I don’t think `scale_reshaped` and `shift_reshaped` are used to modify the filter, but I think they should? Is this intended/is my understanding correct? 3) Why do you do`*x[2]+x[3]` for `tf.nn.conv2d`? Thanks!

Comment: @JaneSully everything you ponted out is correct. I guess I was too careless. Fixed the issues